# Stacking agents in nodes/end of a path

Tags: anylogic

[Agent Comparison/ Priority for queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZNwk.jpg)

I'm building a model in Anylogic I have a question about visualization.
I have a model that looks like this: Source -> delay -> queue (with preemption option that goes into a delay2) -> seize -> delay3 -> release -> sink.

What I would like to do is make the agents enter the queue but visually keep moving along a circled path while waiting. In my model, I put the queue to a capacity of 1 and then added a preemption option which goes into a delay where the agents move along a circled path. I am able to make them take a lap along the path this way, but since the capacity of the queue can't be less than 1 there is always 1 agent standing still (not going in the preemption option). I would like for all of them to keep moving on the circled path while in the queue. How can I fix this? 
Also, since the seize block has an embedded queue, and it starts where the queue before ends, there are actually two agents standing still at the same place.

Comment: use the wait block instead of a queue... easier to control...

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I will use the wait block instead